# Hierarchical Bayesian Modelling: deriving a Conditional PDF relation

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, hierarchical-bayesian

**Background**

I am currently reading through the book: *Data Analysis: A Bayesian Tutorial, second edition* by D.S. Sivia.
I am stumped by one of the relations that he introduces in the context of model selection, when evaluating the evidence for a model $B$, which is parameterised by $\lambda$, with data $D$ and other relevant background information $I$, i.e.

$prob(D \mid B, I) = \int prob(D \mid \lambda, B, I) \, prob(\lambda \mid B,I)d\lambda$.

Note $prob(\cdot)$ refers to a probability density function.

**Issue**

My issue is concerned with how $prob(D \mid\lambda, B, I)$ is rewritten on page 80, equation (4.5) of the book. The book says:

> Let us also take it that there is a value $\lambda_{0}$ which yields
>   the closest agreement with the measurements; the corresponding
>   probability $prob(D \mid \lambda_{0}, B, I)$ will be the maximum of B's
>   likelihood function. As long as this adjustable parameter lies in the
>   neighbourhood of the optimal value, $\lambda_{0} \pm \delta\lambda$,
>   we would expect a reasonable fit to the data; this can be represented
>   by the Gaussian pdf
>
> $prob(D \mid\lambda, B, I) =  prob(D \mid\lambda_{0}, B, I) \times \exp \left(-\frac{(\lambda - \lambda_{0})^{2}}{2\delta\lambda^{2}} \right)$

Intuitively this relation makes sense to me. However, I cannot seem to be able to derive the relation myself.

**Attempt at solution**

First of all I will say that I am interpreting $\exp \left(-\frac{(\lambda - \lambda_{0})^{2}}{2\delta\lambda^{2}} \right)$ as $prob(\lambda \mid \lambda_{0}, B, I)$, and so I am looking to derive the relation:

$prob(D \mid \lambda, B, I) =  prob(D \mid\lambda_{0}, B, I) \times prob(\lambda \mid \lambda_{0}, B, I)$

I have made numerous attempts at trying to derive the LHS from the RHS or vice versa by applying Bayes' Theorem and/or the chain rule of probability to no avail.
I have also looked into Hierarchical Bayes' statistics (where this example would be a two stage hierarchical model), and from this I believe that $\lambda_{0}$ should be conditioned on the LHS of the equation (i.e. it has implicitly been absorbed into the background info, $I$) so that the relation can be written:

$prob(D \mid \lambda, \lambda_{0}, B, I) =  prob(D \mid \lambda_{0}, B, I) \times prob(\lambda \mid \lambda_{0}, B, I).$

However, I still cannot derive this relation.

Any advice on how to proceed would be very much appreciated, and I apologise in advance if the solution is simply some trivial relation between $prob(A \mid B,C)$, $prob(A \mid C)$ and $prob(B \mid C)$, but I am not aware of one.

Comment: Would I be better posting this on Mathematics Stack Exchange?